# Application/GUI Framework Recommendations

Tags: .net, user-interface, frameworks

I'm a .net developer looking for an application/GUI framework.  I've really only found 1 example of what I am looking for which was provided in a [DevExpress KB aricle](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/AK6758.aspx).

Does anybody have any opinions on this example or can recommend something that resembles this that might be better to use.  I like the Outlook look and feel so the example given is right along the lines of what I'm looking for, I just think there might be something better out there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [SharpDevelop Core](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ICSharpCodeCore.aspx).  It is very good, but there's one caveat: while version 4 is now in WPF, it doesn't follow the Model-View-ViewModel pattern.  If you want something similar that's also MVVM, I suggest [SoapBox Core](http://soapboxcore.com/) *disclaimer: I wrote it*.  It's open source (LGPL) just like SharpDevelop, but it uses MEF for extensibility, which will be part of .NET 4, rather than the a custom add-in architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like the [Smart Client - Composite UI Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480450.aspx). I am not aware of similar frameworks for .NET and tend to think that most companies develop custom solutions for their projects.

Answer (score 0):

The components from ComponentArt are very good, I have purchased and use these, and can recommend them.

I have alo since started using jQuery, Using this with a combination of Custom ASP.NET WebControl and UserControls, once can create some very responsive and lightweight GUI components. Definately worth a look if you need to keep things simple or need something specific.